# Problems Initializing a Struct at Declare Time Using Char Pointer

Tags: c

I am trying to declare and initialize a struct using a char* pointer. Compiling the code below fails if I do anything but

```
thing things[] = {{3,300},{4,*text}};
```

Linux gives me a core dump when it tries to print

```
things[1].detail.text;
```

It works when I do the separate assignment

```
things[1].detail.text = text;


#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{ 
    char *text = "ABC";
    char *text2;

    typedef struct {
        int counter;
        union 
        {
            int number;
            char *text;         
        } detail;
    } thing;

    thing one;
    thing two;   

    one.counter = 1;   
    one.detail.number = 100;

    two.counter = 2;
    two.detail.text = (char *)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(two.detail.text, text);

    thing things[] = {{3,300},{4,*text}};
    //things[1].detail.text = text;  

    printf("%d: %d\n%d: %s\n", one.counter, one.detail.number, two.counter, two.detail.text);
    printf("%d: %d\n%d: %s\n", things[0].counter, things[0].detail.number, things[1].counter, things[1].detail.text);


    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Compile with -Wall and heed thy warnings.

Answer (score 1):

use `thing things[] = {{3,300},{4,text}};`